# Excel VBA - Find out difference in hours

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with value

`09:00 - 21:00`

Trying to find out how can I get the difference in hours, ie. for this example `12`.

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA or excel solution?

Comment: If you are looking for a VBA solution, the `DateDiff` function would appear to be what you need.  This function returns the difference between two dates in the unit of your choice from seconds to years.  You do not say how 9:00 and 21:00 are held.  If they are being held in cells, they are probably being held as dates.  Excel holds dates as doubles. The integer part is the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the fraction part is SecondsSinceMidnight / SecondsInDay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function

```
Function GetHourDifference(cell As Range) As Long
    GetHourDifference = Hour(Split(cell.Value, "-")(1)) - Hour(Split(cell.Value, "-")(0))
End Function
```

to be exploited in your main code as follows

```
MsgBox GetHourDifference(Range("a1"))   '<--| if cell "A1" has value "09:00 - 21:00" it returns: 12
```

Comment: @user1049961 - Be aware that the solution is just subtracting the hour portion of the two times, i.e. completely ignoring minutes.  So both `09:00 - 21:59` and `09:59 - 21:00` are reported as 12 hours, even though the first is 12 hours and 59 minutes and the second is only 11 hours and 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

if your `09.00 - 21.00` is in cell **B7**, then this works:

```
=TIME(RIGHT(B7,5),RIGHT(B7,2),)-TIME(LEFT(B7,5),MID(B7,4,2),)
```

very brute force, as it assumes that the time is always `00.00` and no other characters will ever be included.

Comment: I have just tried this again, with cell B7 containing the example given and my expression as shown and it works - changing the result as the example times are edited. How can you reply that "it assumes the time is always 00.00" - did you actually test it as I have done twice...

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim txtDate As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim varDateDif As Variant, split1 As Variant, split2 As Variant

' Cell with times
txtDate = Range("A2").Value

' Split the cell using the delimiter -
varDateDif = Split(txtDate, "-")

For i = 0 To LBound(varDateDif)
    split1 = varDateDif(i) ' First time
    split2 = varDateDif(i + 1) ' Second time
Next i

' Difference in hours
Range("B2").Value = Abs(CDate(split1) - CDate(split2))
' Difference in minutes
Range("C2").Value = DateDiff("n", split1, split2)

End Sub
```

Comment: the OP specifically asks for the difference in hours, so I don't think minutes are necessary. Also, I think this would be a better answer if you added some explanation rather than a code dump

Comment: Added it as a bonus information, since the OP could find it useful. Added comments for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a formula solution, i'd go with the following:

```
=HOUR(RIGHT(C24,5))-HOUR(LEFT(C24,5))
```

Which works as long as your values are always in the format provided.

If you are looking for a VBA solution I'd go with that of @user3598756